# Customize the TFS web dashboard

Tags: tfs

Like the title says, how can I customize the web dashboard in TFS 2012? I have created my own Work Item Type and would like a shortcut on the home page of Team Web Access. I am using the default Team Web Access page and I would just like to have a shortcut button immediately on the front page instead of in a dropdown, which is where it's contained now.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? Suggested google search: "customize web dashboard in TFS 2015"

Comment: Yes, I've been Googling for hours. I have found pages outlining how to customize extensions or the task board, I want to customize the home page.

Comment: This talks about customizing the home page (first result on google) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920199.aspx In any case it's a good idea to specify in your question what you have already tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I have already read through that link multiple times and it does not contain the answer I am looking for and is unrelated to my question.

Comment: Well, this is a programming site and you might strike lucky that someone sees your question and has had a similar problem, but in general it's about solving programming problems. And software configuration isn't really a programming problem. You might have more luck on superuser, a TFS forum or MS support.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll try elsewhere as well :)

Comment: Your tag is tfs2012, but your text says 2015. Can you please change whichever is incorrect?

Comment: if your customization will only include a "link add" then you can modify the .js files within TFS Server and add a link dynamically; but like Dylan noted, you'll have to do the same operations after any upgrade, since it will be overwritten during upgrade process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to do this.  In TFS 2015 they have the concept of Web Extensions, but that is only for specific extension points which doesn't include changing the home page.

You can do it in an unsupported manner, but I wouldn't recommend it.  You can find the ASPX/CSS/JS files on the server that TFS uses for the web site and hack away at them.  I've known people that have done this before.  But there are probably repercussions when it comes time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I've found a dirty solution to do this without cloning the website and gutting it (as described here: http://awaitwisdom.com/how-to-extend-tfs-team-web-access/). Note that this solution is really dirty and may not fit your project needs.

The solution works by swapping the default work item options (based on the process template you are using).

Use WITADMIN to export your Categories into an XML. Find a work item currently on the front page that you're okay with swapping out for the work item you want to be on the front page. Change "DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE" to "WORKITEMTYPE" in the  tags. Add a new entry:  and it should show up as one of the shortcut buttons on your home page.

I highly recommend doing your modifications with Microsoft TFS Power Tools 2012.